# How to Debug Com dll (accessed through Interop) in IIS 7.0( Windows Server 2008 R2) invoked from ASPX Page using VB 6.0

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, com, interop

Can anybody tell how to debug the Com Dll in IIS 7.0 using VB 6.0 in Windows Server 2008 R2.
I am able to hit break point in VB 6.0 accessed from Console Application using interop dlll.Through ASPX pages in IIS 7.0 I am getting the following Exception

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'XCreateUser.XAcctUserProfileClass'
>   to interface type 'XCreateUser._XAcctUserProfile'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{7A48FABA-CCC8-4FA6-94E8-803F6CF121F2}' failed due
>   to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A

Already DLL built and registered and com interop dll generated.

Please somebody show some light on this

Answer (score 2):

> Already DLL built and registered

"Registered" is the problem here, it wasn't correctly registered.  This is an exception message that's generated by the CLR when it tries to locate the proxy for a .NET component that is [ComVisible].  A proxy is required to make a call to a COM component from a worker thread that doesn't do anything to help make the call thread-safe.  A thread that's in the MTA, usually a thread-pool thread.

A .NET component is registered with [Regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You forgot to use the `/tlb` argument.

Should be simple to fix.  If you still have trouble then SysInternals' Process Monitor is the weapon of choice.

Comment: My mind is blown at the level of knowledge you have. At both the length and breadth of it. +1

Comment: XCreateUser.dll is com dll , I built this and registered.Created the Interop.XcreateUser.dll for accessing it from asp.net application.Now when i try to debug it is not hitting the break point set in VB 6.0(com dll). Do i really need to use regasm for this? Please Help me on this.

Comment: You are talking about a .NET assembly that you made [ComVisible].  Used in ASP.NET, a runtime for .NET code.  It is completely unclear why you think you need to use VB6.  Or COM interop for that matter, using a .NET library from a web application that runs on ASP.NET is dead-simple, just add a reference to it.  I doubt I can help you further until you figure out what tools you are actually using.

Comment: No I am talking about existing  VB dll , accessed  in ASP.NET Application through Interop dll.Now i want to debug VB dll in VB 6.0  to see the flow and values passed. Dev Environtment is Windows 2008 R2 (64 bit). VS 2008 and VB 6.0 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I generally debug these things as you say through a console or windows forms application.  You can always add logging to your web app to see what parameters are being passed to it.

Generally errors like the above are setup issues when running on a 64 bit platform and when utilizing 32 bit dlls.  One thing to make sure of is that your application pool allows 32 bit applications.  In IIS Manager right click on the application pool your website is running under and go to Advanced Settings->Enable 32 bit Applications.  Set that to True.

You'll also need to make sure that your 32 bit dll is registered in the 32 bit registry hive.  C:\Windows\syswow64\regsvr32 is the version you'll need to use to register this dll.